# Should i cache manifest.json in service worker

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I am using service worker. Should I cache my `manifest.json` file. Does it makes sense?
Also how frequently does the browser fetch this file.

Answer (score 22):

Yes you should cache your manifest.json file, because if you a building a PWA, then it must have a functionality to `Add to home screen`. In your manifest file, it contains a `start_url` that needs to be cached by service worker and should return a 200 response when offline.

Let's assume anyone is offline browsing your app and hasn't added the web app on home screen, then it will ask user if he/she wants to add to home screen or not provided you have cached your manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

It is called at every page load (assuming that its not an SPA).  Its also static anyway, might as well cache it in my opinion saves the trouble of calling the server for that file.